# laravel set attribute won't append to json key

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, octobercms

I have a loop setting some json values.

```
 if (isset($product->customfields)) {
            foreach ($product->customfields as $customfield) {
                $fieldId = $customfield['custom_field_id'];
                // Grab custom field template code
                $field = CustomField::find($fieldId);

                $product->attributes['display_name'] = $field->display_name;

            }
}
```

Where the display name im trying to add is here

```
$product->attributes['display_name'] = $field->display_name;
```

In my dump I can see the json as this

```
 "id":"20",
 "display_name":"Size",
   "customfields":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "product_id":"20",
         "store_id":null,
         "custom_field_id":"1",
         "value":"RED",
         "created_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:00",
         "updated_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:14"
      },
```

But when I try to change to EITHER of this

```
 $product->attributes['customfields']['display_name'] = $field->display_name;


 $product->attributes['customfields'] = $field->display_name;
```

I just get this

```
"id":"20",
"customfields":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "product_id":"20",
         "store_id":null,
         "custom_field_id":"1",
         "value":"RED",
         "created_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:00",
         "updated_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:14"
      },
```

How do I set the attribute to add to the customfields key?

Edit:

The full file http://kopy.io/LQTDi

thanks to @Manish for suggesting

$product->customfields-['display_name'] = $field->display_name;

which now returns

```
"customfields":{  
      "0":{  
         "id":"1",
         "product_id":"10000",
         "store_id":null,
         "custom_field_id":"1",
         "value":"RED",
         "created_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:00",
         "updated_at":"2016-09-14 09:32:14"
      },
      "1":{  
         "id":"2",
         "product_id":"10000",
         "store_id":null,
         "custom_field_id":"2",
         "value":"",
         "created_at":"2016-09-14 10:22:14",
         "updated_at":"2016-09-14 10:22:14"
      },
      "display_name":"Size"
   },
```

But in the custom display name there are two fields with Size and Color.  I think I maybe need to make a new loop and loop the display_name through.  If this is the case then please advise and I will do this instead.

Comment: I am pretty surprised that it actually even works, as `attributes` property in `Eloquent\Model` class is protected. You should get error `Indirect modification of overloaded property` or something like that. Are you sure you're not supressing any erros within that code?

Comment: Errors are on.  However I am using OcotberCMS, so maybe it has something to do with the above code actually working.

Comment: Indeed. OctoberCMS alters property visibility https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Database/Model.php#L48

Comment: Did you try like this `$product->customfields['display_name'] = $field->display_name;`

Comment: @Manish That somewhat works, it adds display name inside customfields but not in the id "1".  When I have multiple customvalues it will go customfields: [ { "id":1 },  {"id":2}, etc.  How would I loop each display_name inside each object?

Comment: Could you explain more regarding this with proper example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ServerSideSkittles May be i got your point. May be i was wrong but as per your details i think you need this.

```
if (isset($product->customfields)) {

                foreach ($product->customfields as $customfieldKey => $customfieldVal) {
                    $fieldId = $customfieldVal['custom_field_id'];
                    // Grab custom field template code
                    $field = CustomField::find($fieldId);

                    $product->customfields[$customfieldKey]['display_name'] = $field->display_name;
                }
    }
```

Try use this. May be this will sort out the issue.

Comment: This is amazing!  I was reediting my question and you posted this gem.  Thankyou very much as I was not doing a good job of explaining the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42645072/laravel-eloquent-json-column-updating-not-working?answertab=active#tab-top)?

```
$product->setAttribute ('customfields->display_name', 'Display name of my column');
```

However, taking a step back, and circumventing entirely the point of your question, one could argue that you don't really want to hard-code the display name in your database model at all.  Display names should be something that's managed in your translation/localisation file.

In your Blade template file, try:

```
{{ __($my_field_id) }}
```

And then you would have a translation for your `field-id` in the localisation file.